# Fragment Return Shared Element Transition not working. Need additional View to work

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I made a shared element transition for fragment. My transition code as below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Transition changeTransform = TransitionInflater.from(this).
    inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);
    mainFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransform);
    secondFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeTransform);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(findViewById(R.id.button_view), "MyTransition");
    fragmentTransaction
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment, MainFragment.TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

My transition xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeBounds />
    <changeTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

My mainFragment as below

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/button_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:transitionName="MyTransition"
        android:onClick="clickButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
````

My secondFragment as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/base_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/button_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0f0"
            android:transitionName="MyTransition"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The transition happen from mainFragment to secondFragment smoothly. However upon return from secondFragment to mainFragment, the transition would only be okay if I have the `base_view` in the secondFragment. If I remove the `base_view` from the secondFragment, then the returnTransition is not working. Why is the 'additional' view needed to make the return transition happen?

Answer (score 0):

After some experiment, in order to ensure the return transition animation still works when `base_view` is not there anymore... use `layout_margin` instead of `padding` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/button_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0f0"
            android:transitionName="MyTransition"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```